# How to read form-data with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, firefox

In my controller the result of `request.body.read` is:

```
=============
--AJAX-----------------------1267183973160
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="1261400603_page_white_word.png"; filename="1261400603_page_white_word.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

thefile
--AJAX-----------------------1267183973160
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="1261400536_page_white_excel.png"; filename="1261400536_page_white_excel.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

thefile
--AJAX-----------------------1267183973160--
=============
```

It contains n form-data (2 in my example), my goal is to loop through the n form-data and get the data `name`, `filename` and a file uploaded, in my example I replaced the binary data by `thefile`.

here is the content of the params hash

```
{"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"photos", "1265144945_395.jpg"=>#<File:/var/folders/BT/BTpdsWBkF6myaI-sl3+1NU+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20100226-273-1un364r-0>}
```

Cheers

Comment: And what is in `params` hash?

Comment: I added the params content...

Comment: Does the file pointed to by params exist?  What are it's contents?

Comment: It is the file uploaded, where this param come from? maybe the Rack::Utils::Multipart.parse_mulitpart as you said... very interesting, I have to check this. Important detail... I use Rails 3.0.0 beta

Comment: You can found the answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306910/paperclip-and-xhr-sendasbinary/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306910/paperclip-and-xhr-sendasbinary/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paperclip and xhr.sendAsBinary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306910/paperclip-and-xhr-sendasbinary)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [attachment_fu](http://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu)?  They are battle-tested and will do better than using `request.body`.  In any case, you could parse `request.body` as follows but it's not the best solution.

```
inputs =  request.body.read.split(/--ajax-+\d+-*/mi)

inputs.each do |input| 
  input.scan(/(.*)[\n\r]{2,4}(.*)/m) do |header, file| 
    header.scan(/name=["'](.*)["'];\s+filename=["'](.*)["']/) do |name, filename|
      puts name
      puts filename
    end
    puts file
  end
end
```

Edit:  So that params parsing is probably the job of [Rack::Utils::Multipart.parse_mulitpart](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Utils/Multipart.html#M000081).  One should probably reuse the regex's from the source of that to parse this a bit more robustly.  Also, it looks like rack is creating a tmp file for you of some sort.  Can you check the contents of that file?

Comment: well, the data are submitted by an ajax request with sendAsBinary (only Firefox 3) and paperclip doesn't catch the file (don't know why!), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306910/paperclip-and-xhr-sendasbinary and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325827/diff-between-xhr-sendasbinary-and-classic-file-submit-in-http-request thanks

Comment: Oh great.. I had seen the first of those two questions and was wondering what the answer would be...

Comment: A posted the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306910/paperclip-and-xhr-sendasbinary/