# File posted to MVC Controller is null

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to post three things to my MVC Controller: one image and two strings.

On the **View**, I've got a form that uses `enctype="multipart/form-data"` that automatically submits the form after an image file is selected.  This is the submit handler for this form:

```
    $("#PhotoUploadForm").on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var ImageData = $("#PhotoUploadFileInput").val();
        var GuestNumber = $("#GuestID").val();
        var TCSA_ID = vm.GetSelectedTreatmentAreaTCSA_ID(vm.Photographs.SelectedTreatmentArea());

        var dto = {
            ImageData: ImageData,
            GuestNumber: GuestNumber,
            TCSA_ID: TCSA_ID
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'SaveImage',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "multipart/form-data",
            data: ko.toJSON(dto),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(submitted);
            }
        });
    });
```

The `dto` object is defined in my **Model**:

```
public class PhotoUploadDTO
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageData { get; set; }
    public string GuestNumber { get; set; }
    public string TCSA_ID { get; set; }
}
```

And in my **Controller**, I have an action that takes in `dto` as a parameter:

```
   public ActionResult SaveImage(PhotoUploadDTO dto)
   {
     //etc.
   }
```

When I try to post `dto`, everything gets posted as null.  This problematic for me because I want to be able to post the image and two strings to the controller simultaneously.

I suspect that the issue is with `var ImageData` (which is set to the value of `<input type="file" id="PhotoUploadFileInput">` on my View), and that it is being posted as `C:/fakepath/etc.` but not as the actual image file.  It's frustrating because I know it wouldn't even be an issue if I had a form that *just* posted the image, but I *need* to use this submit handler and I don't know how to bring the actual image data into it.

Why is the data `null` when it hits the MVC Controller, and how can I post these three items while still being able to use a submit handler?

Comment: You can't upload a file via ajax. There are some workarounds such as uploading the file via an iframe, but you just can't do it this way unfortunately.

Comment: I think your comment should suffice as an answer, if you want to post it as an answer.

Comment: @MelanciaUK 'You can't upload a file via ajax *this way' sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Christopher.Cubells What? You can. Using `XMLHttpRequest` `sendAsBinary()` or the `File API` for new browsers.

Comment: You can find a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306910/paperclip-and-xhr-sendasbinary

Comment: I'm confused, aren't those all different ways than what the OP is doing?.. and still using those techniques are all invalid for older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading a file via ajax is a tricky thing. Some of the most modern web browsers handle this by using the [File API](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/uploading-files-with-ajax--net-21077) which will indeed work for uploading a file via ajax. However, using this solution will not work with people on older browsers.

Your best bet is using a jquery plugin or something similar that will fall back on techniques such as uploading the file via an iframe or other workarounds.

Comment: I figured out that the jQuery File Upload plugin works here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data